# Custom HTML Page in Pentaho User Console 5

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde, pentaho-ctools

I need to know how to create a custom HTML page with the related static resource - css, js and images - into Pentaho User Console version 5 that use Jackrabbit as its repository.

I've checked the pentaho wiki and help pages but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSS and JavaScript files**

Upload CSS and JS files

1. Browse files > home > New folder.. > Name: `test`
2. home > test > Upload... > `{choose files to upload from file system; e.g. test.css and test.js}`

Create dashboard, add resources

1. Create new CDE dashboard [Home > Create New > CDE Dashbaord]
2. Layout Panel (first, default) > Layout Structure menu (top left) > `Add Resource` > `Resource type: {choose: CSS / JavaScript}; External File`
3. Choose `Resource file` by clicking on a `^` button. Navigate to `home/test/test.css` or `home/test/test.js`

All resource files defined in `Layout structure` are attached to dashboard's HTML code.

**Images**

I prefer to store image files within Pentaho server folder.

- pentaho-solutions/system/pentaho-cdf-dd/images
- which can be later referred from HTML as `<img src="images/test_logo.png"/>`
- or from CSS as `background-image: url('test-logo.png');`

Comment: I see, so we no more have html rendered page like the one that exist in sequence action (xaction).